# How to make all possible pairs from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
a = ["a","b","c"]
a.each_cons(2).to_a # => [["a", "b"], ["b", "c"]]
```

I want three possible pairs from this array

Comment: What are the three possible pairs? Do you want all possible pairs (as in the title) or three possible pairs (as in the question)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation) to generate sub-arrays with all combination.

```
a.permutation(2).to_a
# => [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["b", "c"], ["c", "a"], ["c", "b"]]
```

Following this you can pick 3 random arrays using [Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-sample) (*assuming you want to pick random sub-arrays*). Here:

```
a.permutation(2).to_a.sample(3)
# => [["c", "b"], ["c", "a"], ["b", "c"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = ["a","b","c"]
a.permutation(2).to_a.take(3)
#  => [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "a"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["a","b","c"]
a.combination(2).to_a # => [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```